# How to get CSS class property in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
.test {
    width:80px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#808080;
    margin:20px;
}
```

HTML -

```
<div class="test">Click Here</div>
```

In JavaScript i want to get `margin:20px`

Comment: I just leave it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle#Example.

Comment: you can also read this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/can-getelementsbyclassname-change-style) hope it helps

Comment: include jQuery and use this is simpler and better

$('.test').css( "margin" );

Comment: @KareemHashem "Simple" not always "Better".

Comment: but in this case it is better than write many lines jQuery does in one line

Comment: Assuming you have the same `test` class, but also an inline style: `<div class="test" style="margin: 10px">Click Here</div>` do you want to have the `margin` defined by the class (20px) or the margin applied to the element (that can be 20px without inline and 10px with inline)? In the second case the `getComputedStyle` is ok, as the others says, in the first case you need a different approach.

Comment: Sorry this is  `internal` or `external` css

Comment: @ZER0 In first case you should first remove style attribute node and then get style with `getComputedStyle`.

Comment: @Givi, no. In the first case you should access directly to the css rule. Assuming for instance you have: `<div class="test foo">Click here</div>` where both of them are set the `margin`. If you want the margin applied, `getComputedStyle` is fine. If you want the margin of `test`, then you need a different approach. Because the question is not clear about that – it want the margin from `test`? Or the margin applied to the element? – I just highlight that fact, in order to be sure we understand the original request.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

For modern browsers you can use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle):

```
var elem,
    style;
elem = document.querySelector('.test');
style = getComputedStyle(elem);
style.marginTop; //`20px`
style.marginRight; //`20px`
style.marginBottom; //`20px`
style.marginLeft; //`20px`
```

`margin` is a composite style, and not reliable cross-browser. Each of `-top` `-right`, `-bottom`, and `-left` should be accessed individually.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pBg9e/)

Comment: Showing blank when i am using `alert(style.margin);`

Comment: include jQuery and use this is simpler and better $('.test').css( "margin" );

Comment: @Chinmay What browser do you use?

Comment: Latest browser `Mozilla 25.0.1`

Comment: hello @zzzzBov your code also working in chrome but not working in mozilla. :(

Comment: @Chinmay for me it's working in all modern browsers *(Chrome, Opera, Mozilla, IE11)*

Comment: @Chinmay, wrote this quick and had to run to a meeting. Turns out that the composite `margin` isn't cross-browser compatible, but the individual `marginTop` etc properties appear to work. The general idea works, but I hadn't tested the code cross browser.

Comment: this solution works, but what if you want to get a lets say width that is set to 80%, and you want to see if it is percentages or pixels, this won't work

Comment: @andrejs well, considering that wasn't what was asked, it's not included in my answer. There are other questions that cover accessing the calculated values of percentages.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is the best way to get the computed values. I personally needed the pre-computed value. Say for instance 'height' being set to a 'calc()' value. I wrote the following jQuery function to access the value from the style sheet. This script handles nested 'media' and 'supports' queries, CORS errors, and should provide the final cascaded precomputed value for accessible properties.

```js
$.fn.cssStyle = function() {
  var sheets = document.styleSheets, ret = [];
  var el = this.get(0);
  var q = function(rules){
   for (var r in rules) {
    var rule = rules[r];
    if(rule instanceof CSSMediaRule && window.matchMedia(rule.conditionText).matches){
     ret.concat(q(rule.rules || rule.cssRules));
    } else if(rule instanceof CSSSupportsRule){
     try{
      if(CSS.supports(rule.conditionText)){
       ret.concat(q(rule.rules || rule.cssRules));
      }
     } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
     }
    } else if(rule instanceof CSSStyleRule){
     try{
      if(el.matches(rule.selectorText)){
       ret.push(rule.style);
      }
     } catch(e){
      console.error(e);
     }
    }
   }
  };
  for (var i in sheets) {
   try{
    q(sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules);
   } catch(e){
    console.error(e);
   }
  }
  return ret.pop();
 };
  
  // Your element
  console.log($('body').cssStyle().height);
```

Comment: I just tried this code with a very simple case, and it worked, but there's something that doesn't make sense to me. The code `ret.concat(q(rule.rules || rule.cssRules));` looks like it expects something to be returned from the `q` function, but that function has no return value. I'm guessing that the real work is done by accumulating values in `ret`, but you would be accumulating `undefined` values this way.

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery:

```
   $('.class').css( "backgroundColor" );
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach (still experimental) could be [computedStyleMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/computedStyleMap):

```
const computedStyleMap = document.getElementById('my-id').computedStyleMap();
computedStyleMap.get('overflow-x'); // {value: 'scroll'}
computedStyleMap.has('padding-right'); // false
computedStyleMap.entries(); // Iterator {}
```

Comment: [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/computedStyleMap#browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

I've just released an npm package for this purpose exactly. You can find it here on npm or github:

npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylerjs

github: https://github.com/tjcafferkey/stylerjs

you would use it like so

```
var styles = styler('.class-name').get(['height', 'width']);
```

and styles would equal

```
{height: "50px", width: "50px"}
```

So you could just get the values like so

```
var height = styles.height;
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I removed the "export default " on the first line and added a `<script src="js/styler.js"></script>` to get it to work.