# Cheerio get class properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cheerio

How can I get css property for selector?

having html

```
<body>
  <a class="my_class" href="/" title="link"/>
</body>
```

and some properties for `my_class`

```
.my_class {
  color: red
}
```

in JS code I'm using cheerio lib:

```
var content = cheerio.load(html_content_page);
var selector = "a.my_class";
```

So, how can I get `color` property using above selector?

Comment: Ok, answer on similar question from maintainers: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/357#issuecomment-31659300

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.my_class').css('color')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377835/how-to-get-css-class-property-in-javascript

Comment: Guys, thank for fast reply, it doesn't work for me because  I'm using 'cheerio' lib rather than 'jquery', so it seems to me that this lib can only parse css properties enclosed in 'style' tag within html, but in my case they are in separated css file.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript, you can use `getComputedStyle()` for inline styling or rules declared in stylesheet

Snippet below

```js
var a=document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]
console.log(getComputedStyle(a).color);
console.log(getComputedStyle(a).backgroundColor);
```

```css
.my_class {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a class="my_class" href="/" title="link"/ style="background:blue">
</body>
```

Comment: I think that I couldn't pass Cheerio object into getComputedStyle function?!

Comment: I'm using cheerio lib for parsing html page (from arbitrary site), so this page keeps css rules in separated file
I've found desired answer there: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/357#issuecomment-31659300