# Getting an intermediate value for CSS custom prop

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to get an intermediate value for CSS custom prop using JS?

I have a custom prop `--text--primary` which is defined using other prop:

```css
--gray90: #333;
--text--primary: var(--gray90);
```

What I want is by having `--text--primary`, get an intermediate value: `--gray90`. I know, there is `getPropertyValue` but it works with computed values only, so it returns `#333`. Is there a way to do it without parsing the CSS?

Comment: You could loop over the [document.styleSheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/styleSheets) but not sure if that is really optimal.

Comment: @Reyno, yep, unfortunately that would be pretty heavy in my case

Comment: There's a fairly recent answer from Bernesto on [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377835/how-to-get-css-class-property-in-javascript which looks promising as it's trying to get intermediate values (which the actual question wasn't). I haven't tried it though and it looks quite heavy code-wise.

Comment: @AHaworth thanks, but that's basically what I wanted to avoid. I hoped that there is a native way of getting them via some JS helper, but it's understandable that there is none, since the whole idea might be considered as pretty fishy. I'll go with parsing CSS then.