# How to get real value in percents when using getComputedStyle()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I compare different CSS values of the same CSS declaration applied to the same element from different style sheets and to get the final CSS value I use `getComputedStyle()`. I know that it returns computed values in px. But is it possible at that to get the real value in percents from the very CSS?

I mean with the code

```js
let element = document.querySelector('.col');
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(element).width);
```

```css
.col{
width:40%;
}
.col{
width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col"></div>
```

I get a value in px, but I would like to get 50% specfied in the very CSS

Is there a way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get CSS class property in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377835/how-to-get-css-class-property-in-javascript)

Comment: @DBS I know about `styleSheets.cssRules` and they return values in percents, but they don't know which value is the final. The `getComputedStyle()` returns only the final value but computed in px and not in percents, that's the problem.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the percentage value? If you know the style is a percentage, you could always work backwards with the pixel value and the parent size to work it out.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I've got it.